# rendering twitter bootstrap modal in rails upon redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a functioning modal link that is clickable from a certain page in my views:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manifesto-modal">Manifesto &amp; Rules</a>
```

In addition to it being clickable on this page, I would like it to be displayed by default upon redirect to this page. I haven't found a great approach to coding this from the controller or otherwise, but can't imagine it would require too much. Input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this JavaScript. It's probably not the best approach and I'd be interested to hear peoples' thoughts on it:

```
  if ( window.location.pathname == "/edit_profile" ) {
    $('#manifesto-modal').modal('show');
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

according to the docs, you could use [the flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) (untested):

```
redirect_to your_path, flash: { manifesto_modal: true }
```

then in your view :

```
<% if flash[:manifesto_modal] %>
  // a script to display modal on document ready
<% end %>
```

Comment: like this?   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#manifesto_modal").dialog({modal: true});
    });

Comment: i found this link but did not have success with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285600/show-a-modal-right-after-signup

Comment: ok i found that if i add this: $('#manifesto-modal').modal('show'); in  the main "users.js" file of my rails asset pipeline, the modal pops open  automatically on my "edit_profile" page as I want it to. unfortunately, it now opens automatically on every page. how do i restrict this javascript to a certain page? embedding the script in the view html.erb wasn't working:       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#manifesto-modal').modal('show');
          });
      </script>

Comment: remember to use <% if... %> and include your script only if you are redirected